# Pythonic algorithm for applying a function to a 3D array along the first axis indices

Tags: arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have a 3D array like A

```
A = np.random.randint(20,size=(4,2,2))
array([[[18,  8],
    [ 2, 11]],

   [[ 9,  8],
    [ 9, 10]],

   [[ 0,  1],
    [10,  6]],

   [[ 1,  8],
    [ 4,  2]]])
```

What I want to do is to apply a function to some indices along the axis=0. For example, I want to multiply the A[1] and A[3] by 2 and add 10 to them. I know one option is this:

```
for index in [1,3]:
    A[index] = A[index]*2+10
```

Which gives:

```
array([[[18,  8],
        [ 2, 11]],

       [[28, 26],
        [28, 30]],

       [[ 0,  1],
        [10,  6]],

       [[12, 26],
        [18, 14]]])
```

But my original array is of the size of (2500, 300, 300) and I need to apply the function to 500 non-consecutive indices along the axis=0 every time. Is there a faster and more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: No, they are no regularly spaced. They are like 5 sets of 500 random integers which will be used for applying 5 different functions to 2500 indices in the first axis. @unutbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use stepped slicing

```
A[1::2] = A[1::2] * 2 + 10
A

array([[[18,  8],
        [ 2, 11]],

       [[28, 26],
        [28, 30]],

       [[ 0,  1],
        [10,  6]],

       [[12, 26],
        [18, 14]]])
```

Or assuming your slice is named `slc`

```
A[slc] = A[slc] * 2 + 10
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, my indices are not regularly spaced. So I can not use stepped slicing. But thanks ;)

Comment: @Monobakht so do you know what the indices will be when you are applying the function?

Comment: Yes, I do have a list of 500 indices in my case.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.